# Executing an R script in python via subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, r, subprocess, os.system

When I execute the script in R, it is:

```
$ R --vanilla --args test_matrix.csv < hierarchical_clustering.R > out.txt
```

In Python, it works if I use:

```
process = subprocess.call("R --vanilla --args "+output_filename+"_DM_Instances_R.csv < /home/kevin/AV-labels/Results/R/hierarchical_clustering.R > "+output_filename+"_out.txt", shell=True)
```

But this method doesn't provide the `process.wait()` function.

So, I would like to use the `subprocess.Popen`, I tried:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['R', '--vanilla', '--args', "\'"+output_filename+"_DM_Instances_R.csv\'",  '<', '/home/kevin/AV-labels/Results/R/hierarchical_clustering.R'])
```

But it didn't work, Python just opened R but didn't execute my script.

Comment: have you tried with shell=True, i.e: subprocess.Popen(['R', '--vanilla', '--args', "\'"+output_filename+"_DM_Instances_R.csv\'", '<', '/home/kevin/AV-labels/Results/R/hierarchical_clustering.R'], shell=True)

Comment: It says:Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla' But the '--vanilla' is there... Pls help!! Thanks!!

Comment: According to 'R --help', the '--args' argument means 'Skip the rest of the command line'. This is probably not what you mean. Have you got command line that you could show us that works in the shell?

Comment: I mean... when I run my script in R, it works with 
$ R --vanilla --args test_matrix.csv < hierarchical_clustering.R > out.txt

Besides, when I use the subprocess.call in python, it works as well... but i need the subprocess.Popen so that I can use the wait() function.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of 'R', give it the path to Rscript. I had the same problem. Opens up R but doesn't execute my script. You need to call Rscript (instead of R) to actually execute the script.

```
retcode = subprocess.call("/Pathto/Rscript --vanilla /Pathto/test.R", shell=True)
```

This works for me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by putting everything into the brackets..

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["R --vanilla --args "+output_filename+"_DM_Instances_R.csv < /home/kevin/AV-labels/Results/R/hierarchical_clustering.R > "+output_filename+"_out.txt"], shell=True)
process.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. You might want to consider using the [`Rscript`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/Rscript) frontend, which makes
   [running scripts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scripting-with-R) easier; you can pass the script filename directly
   as a parameter, and do not need to read the script in through standard input.
2. You don't need the shell for just redirecting standard output to a file, you can
   do that directly with `subprocess.Popen`.

Example:

```
import subprocess

output_name = 'something'
script_filename = 'hierarchical_clustering.R'
param_filename = '%s_DM_Instances_R.csv' % output_name
result_filename = '%s_out.txt' % output_name
with open(result_filename, 'wb') as result:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', script_filename, param_filename],
                               stdout=result);
    process.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually execute it fully ^^ try the following

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['R', '--vanilla', '--args', '\\%s_DM_Instances_R.csv\\' % output_filename, '<', '/home/kevin/AV-labels/Results/R/hierarchical_clustering.R'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
process.communicate()#[0] is stdout
```

Comment: It says:Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'

But the '--vanilla' is there... Pls help!! Thanks!!

Comment: I have never used R before and don't know the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Keven's solution works for my requirement. Just to give another example about @Kevin's solution. You can pass more parameters to the rscript with python-style string:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["R --vanilla --args %s %d %.2f < /path/to/your/rscript/transformMatrixToSparseMatrix.R" % ("sparse", 11, 0.98) ], shell=True)
process.wait()
```

Also, to make things easier you could create an R executable file. For this you just need to add this in the first line of the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla --default-packages=utils
```

Reference: [Using R as a scripting language with Rscript](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/using-r-as-a-scripting-language-with-rscript.html) or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894365/running-r-script-from-python)