# how to open a new bash window from python and insert commands into the new bash window

Tags: python, bash, r

I have been attempting, with little success, to open a terminal or konsole window from python and to insert commands into the terminal or konsole window.

So far, I have the following:

```
import os

os.system('konsole')
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to pipe the commands from the python prompt window to the terminal or konsole window.

This may help. I am trying to run commands from python into R (stats programming language).  i.e. open konsole from python -> have letter R typed into the konsole so that R will start in the konsole -> insert R commands, coded in a python script, into the konsole running R.  If anyone has an easier idea could you please share.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need the console to opened with the typed R commands, or do you just need to execute some commands in R?

Answer (score 6):

If all that you need python for is to send commands to R, why not use [RPy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) ? Else, try writing your commands to a temp file, invoke [R in batch mode](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/BATCH.html) with the file and then flush it. 
PS: You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434569/a-question-about-execute-an-r-script-in-python) as well for pointers.