# Running R script from python

Tags: python, r

I searched for this question and found some answers on this, but none of them seem to work. This is the script that I'm using in python to run my R script.

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla -e 'source(\"/pathto/MyrScript.r\")'", shell=True)
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
Calls: source ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table
Execution halted
```

and here is the content of my R script (pretty simple!)

```
data = read.csv('features.csv')
data1 = read.csv("BagofWords.csv")
merged = merge(data,data1)
write.table(merged, "merged.csv",quote=FALSE,sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(merged$fileName))
{
        fileConn<-file(paste("output/",toString(merged$fileName[i]),".txt",sep=""))
        writeLines((toString(merged$BagofWord[i])),fileConn)
        close(fileConn)
}
```

The r script is working fine, when I use `source('MyrScript.r')` in r commandline. Moreover, when I try to use the exact command which I pass to the `subprocess.call` function (i.e., `/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla -e 'source("/pathto/MyrScript.r")'`) in my commandline it works find, I don't really get what's the problem.

Comment: Try specifying the complete filepath to your csv files, perhaps?

Comment: Try `strace` to see what the difference between `exec` calls is.

Answer (score 81):

I would not trust too much the *source* within the `Rscript` call as you may not completely understand where are you running your different *nested* R sessions. The process may fail because of simple things such as your working directory not being the one you think.

`Rscript` lets you directly run an script (see `man Rscript` if you are using Linux).

Then you can do directly:

```
subprocess.call ("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla /pathto/MyrScript.r", shell=True)
```

or better parsing the `Rscript` command and its parameters as a list

```
subprocess.call (["/usr/bin/Rscript", "--vanilla", "/pathto/MyrScript.r"])
```

Also, to make things easier you could create an **R executable file**. For this you just need to add this in the first line of the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript
```

and give it execution rights. See [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/using-r-as-a-scripting-language-with-rscript.html) for detalis.

Then you can just do your python call as if it was any other shell command or script:

```
subprocess.call ("/pathto/MyrScript.r")
```

Comment: subprocess.call() didn't work in my case, but subprocess.Popen() works for me. Here is the example:  process = subprocess.Popen(["R --vanilla --args %s %d %.2f < /path/to/your/rscript/transformMatrixToSparseMatrix.R" % ("sparse", 11, 0.98) ], shell=True)
process.wait()

Comment: All this worked the same for me: ```subprocess.call (['Rscript', '--vanilla', 'MyrScript.r'])

subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', '--vanilla', 'MyrScript.r'])

subprocess.call ('Rscript --vanilla MyrScript.r', shell=True)

subprocess.Popen('Rscript --vanilla MyrScript.r', shell=True)``` If you do not break your parameters into a list is when you need to use `shell+True` I am not sure about parsing the arguments into Rscript using `<`

Answer (score 33):

I think RPy2 is worth looking into, here is a cool presentation on R-bloggers.com to get you started:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-r-from-python-using-rpy2/

Essentially, it allows you to have access to R libraries with R objects that provides both a high level and low level interface.

Here are the docs on the most recent version: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/

I like to point Python users to Anaconda, and if you use the package manager, `conda`, to install `rpy2`, it will also ensure you install R.

```
$ conda install rpy2
```

And here's a vignet based on the documents' introduction:

```
>>> from rpy2 import robjects
>>> pi = robjects.r['pi']
>>> pi
R object with classes: ('numeric',) mapped to:
<FloatVector - Python:0x7fde1c00a088 / R:0x562b8fbbe118>
[3.141593]

>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> base = importr('base')
>>> utils = importr('utils')

>>> import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
>>> utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
>>> packnames = ('ggplot2', 'hexbin')
>>> from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
>>> names_to_install = [x for x in packnames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]
>>> if len(names_to_install) > 0:
...     utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))
```

And running an R snippet:

```
>>> robjects.r('''
...         # create a function `f`
...         f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
...             if (verbose) {
...                 cat("I am calling f().\n")
...             }
...             2 * pi * r
...         }
...         # call the function `f` with argument value 3
...         f(3)
...         ''')
R object with classes: ('numeric',) mapped to:
<FloatVector - Python:0x7fde1be0d8c8 / R:0x562b91196b18>
[18.849556]
```

And a small self-contained graphics demo:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
graphics = importr('graphics')
grdevices = importr('grDevices')
base = importr('base')
stats = importr('stats')

import array

x = array.array('i', range(10))
y = stats.rnorm(10)

grdevices.X11()

graphics.par(mfrow = array.array('i', [2,2]))
graphics.plot(x, y, ylab = "foo/bar", col = "red")

kwargs = {'ylab':"foo/bar", 'type':"b", 'col':"blue", 'log':"x"}
graphics.plot(x, y, **kwargs)


m = base.matrix(stats.rnorm(100), ncol=5)
pca = stats.princomp(m)
graphics.plot(pca, main="Eigen values")
stats.biplot(pca, main="biplot")
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code should work out:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r.source("/pathto/MyrScript.r", encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest using a system call to there are many differences between python and R especially when passing around data.

There are many standard libraries to call R from Python to choose from see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716923/python-interface-for-r-programming-language)

Comment: Hi, here, I just need to run a simple script, so I don't want to stuck with setting up rpy2 or other libraries.

Comment: @Ehsan its fairly simple to setup and you will avoid reinventing the wheel. Are you on windows, mac or linux?

Comment: @Ehsan and another suggestion if all your doing is loading a csv file with R why not just rewrite the R code into python?

Comment: I'm using linux, it's not just loading a csv file, but I will take a loot at rpy2 and see how is it:)

Comment: yeah if your on ubuntu its as simple as `sudo apt-get install python-rpy2`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a line to the beginning of your R script that says:

```
setwd("path-to-working-directory")
```

Except, replace the path with the path to the folder containing the files `features.csv` and `BagofWords.csv`.

I think the problem you are having is because when you run this script from R your working directory is already the correct path, but when you run the script from python, it defaults to a working directory somewhere else (likely the top of the user directory).

By adding the extra line at the beginning of your R script, you are explicitly setting the working directory and the code to read in these files will work.  Alternatively, you could replace the filenames in `read.csv()` with the full filepaths of these files.

@dmontaner suggested this possibility in his answer:

> The process may fail because of simple things such as your working directory not being the one you think.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want run a script then you can use `system("shell command")` of the `sys` lib available by `import sys`. If you have an usefull output you can print the result by `" > outputfilename"` at the end of your shell command.

For example:

```
import sys

system("ls -al > output.txt")
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed. Is it older/obsolete? Can it save the output as a string?

Comment: I don't know if it's obsolete but yes you can have the output. With this one you call a shell command so if you change the output target with > you can get results back with the output file.