# Trying to run an R script in Python

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I have an R script that outputs a CSV that I would like to run in Python.

For example, lets say the R script simply creates a dataframe and outputs a CSV file to my desktop.

**sample.r**

```
x <- c(1,2,4)
y <- c("A","B","C")
z <- data.frame(x,y)
write.csv(z,"c:/users/username/dekstop/z.csv)
```

I'm wondering how I can call the R script in Python in order to create the output.

I have tried utilizing the function below, however it did not create the CSV file.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call ("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla path/sample.r", shell=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894365/running-r-script-from-python) approach?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov I think this questions are different because here OP wants to use subprocess instead of rpy2 external python library.

Comment: What did it create? It looks like the R script has a syntax error (unclosed quote in string path literal) and your Python call is not showing error output.

Comment: @Kyrylo: You are right. It's a closer duplicate of the question you linked instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods you can use to do that. But I think making an R file to a proper executable will solve it not only for python but for other languages. So install fantastic [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R) for R which makes it easy to both specify command-line arguments and implement them and make a file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

require(docopt)
'Usage:
    test.R [-o <output>]

Options:
    -o Output file [default: sim_data.csv]

 ]' -> doc

 opts <- docopt(doc)

 x <- c(1,2,4)
 y <- c("A","B","C")
 z <- data.frame(x,y)
 write.csv(z, opts$o)
```

Save the file as `test.R` and make it executable (Unix/Linux):

```
chmod +x test.R
```

From command like run it

```
./test.R -o path/to/save.csv
```

See help

```
./test.R -h
```

From Python

```
import os
cmd = './test.R -o path/to/save.csv'
os.system(cmd)
```