# How can I use/call an R function in a python script?

Tags: r, python-3.x

My colleague gave me a big `R function` and I have to use it in the pipeline which will be developed in `python3`. In theory I have two options:

1. convert R into python
2. directly use R function in python script (for example by importing like a module)

What do you suggest? and how can I do each of these options?

Comment: Does this link answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894365/running-r-script-from-python

Answer (score 0):

Using rpy2.robjects might help ('function.R' is the r code)

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r.source("function.R")
```

result refers to the output of the function

```
print(robjects.globalenv["result"])
```